# Deploying custom list best practices moss 2007

Tags: 2007, list, deployment

I need to create and deploy a custom list. Is there a best practice way to do this i.e. xml definition or in code? This feature may be redeployed many times as part of a continual integration environment.

Would appreciate your views.

Answer (score 2):

If you will deploy it several times the general recommendation is to use the declarative approach and create a list definition, this also allows users to create an instance of your list as normal.